# How to sort array in ascending order by cosines of array elements with help of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
double P[5] = {9, 17, 151, -3, 5};
```

I need to sort this array with help of pointers in ascending order by cosines of array elements.

Comment: You can use the standard algorithm std::sort.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] .

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is your exact problem. Is your problem doing the sort? Is the problem applying the cosine? Is your problem that you don't know what is meant by using pointers? ... You need to show some effort in solving that problem.

Comment: `ranges::sort(P, std::less<>{}, [](double d) { return std::cos(d); });`

Comment: @Jarod42 Is that a C++20 method of solving the problem? I like it.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, ranges are a C++20 addition.

Comment: @sweenish: With [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) in fact. but C++20 should have `range`, but I don't see (yet?) `sort(range)` on cppreference :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort
#include <cmath>      // cos()  // cosine function
#include <iostream>

// short function to print a std::array, T must have << operator
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void printArray(const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
    for (auto i: arr)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 5> P{9, 17, 151, -3, 5};
    printArray(P);
    // Passing a lambda to std::sort so it compares cosines of the values
    std::sort(P.begin(), 
              P.end(), 
              [](double a, double b) { return cos(a) < cos(b); });
    printArray(P);
}
```

Instead of a C-array, I am using the `std::array` library (C++11). It provides more safety. Since sorting is something that's so common, the C++ standard library provides a function for it, and we can tell it how to compare the values. I do that by passing the lambda as the third argument.

If you really want/have to use a C array, the code doesn't change much.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort
#include <cmath>      // cos()  // cosine function
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// short function to print a std::array, T must have << operator
template <typename T>
void printArray(T *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    double P[5] = {9, 17, 151, -3, 5};
    printArray(P, sizeof(P) / sizeof(double));
    // Passing a lambda to std::sort so it compares cosines of the values
    std::sort(std::begin(P),
              std::end(P),
              [](double a, double b) { return cos(a) < cos(b); });
    printArray(P, sizeof(P) / sizeof(double));
}
```

Comment: [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library).

Comment: Tip : While `std::array` improve on C arrays in many ways, this solution can still work with a `int[5]`. `std::begin(P)` and `std::end(P)` provide "iterators" for C arrays as well as any class type that has appropriate `begin` and `end` members.

Comment: I am aware that C-arrays could be used in my solution. But the use of C-arrays should be discouraged when they don't make sense, and I don't think they make sense here.

Comment: Right, but sorting an array can come up for *other* use cases or in scenarios where it's not possible to change the type of the container. I feel it's worth while to point out that it can also work in those cases.

Comment: I get that, I've also added a modified solution that keeps the C array.

Comment: Also, could have been worse. I could have gone full SO and just yelled at them for not using a vector. ;-)